# Copy large spark Dataframe on disk

Tags: python, apache-spark

I have a large Spark dataframe df which I need to write on local disk.

`df.toPandas().to_csv()` does not work since this consume
too much memory.

How to split the dataframe and write down into a single file ?

Comment: You should consider filtering and projecting the data that you actually need. How large are you talking about?

Comment: yes, thinking of split by slice : df[slicei,:] . How can I do it ?

Comment: Well, Spark dataframes aren't the same as Python lists, so I don't think the slicing notation works in that context